# Controlling inbound traffic to Azure Web Application Service

Tags: azure, port, firewall, azure-virtual-network

I've been searching for this for days and finally found most of the answer in this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-app-service-environment-control-inbound-traffic

It says that you can block ports to your web application service in Azure using a network security group. However, it says I have to keep some ports open.

e.g. "454: Required port used by Azure infrastructure for managing and maintaining App Service Environments via SSL. Do not block traffic to this port. This port is always bound to the public VIP of an ASE."

The question is does this port need to be open to the entire world? One of the options is open to virtual network (what virtual network is this?) I only want it open to the Azure infrastructure. How can I do this? What does VIP of an ASE mean?

Thanks,

Bestist :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is does this port need to be open to the entire world?

It depends on your demand. If you want entire world(Internet) to access your app, you need open it.

> what virtual network is this.

An Azure virtual network (VNet) is a representation of your own network in the cloud. It is a logical isolation of the Azure cloud dedicated to your subscription. You can fully control the IP address blocks, DNS settings, security policies, and route tables within this network. More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-overview).

> I only want it open to the Azure infrastructure. How can I do this?

Yes, you could do it. You should add [Azure data center IP ranges](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653) to NSGs.

If you only want your virtual network devices to access your app services, you could configure NSG such as below:

[image]

> What does VIP of an ASE mean?

VIP:A VIP is the public IP address associated with a VM. More information please refer to this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cloud_solution_architect/2014/11/08/vips-dips-and-pips-in-microsoft-azure/).

ASE: App Service Environments. More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-app-service-environment-intro).

Comment: I would say that ASE in this context means App Service Environment (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-app-service-environment-intro), not Advanced Encryption Standard...

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Yes it helped. I eventually discovered the only way to do what I wanted was to use an App Service Environment (ASE) assuming I don't use a VM to host the web apps. ASE's are too high scale for now.